# Parse json file that save on server in phonegap

Tags: android, json, cordova

My json file that have data

```
[
  {
    "id": 19,
    "name": "Science",
    "quiz": "quiz6"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "name": "general knowledge",
    "quiz": "For banking"
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "name": "Technologies",
    "quiz": "arithmatic"
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "name": "english",
    "quiz": "abcde"
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "name": "computer",
    "quiz": "basic Question"
  }
]
```

save on a server.Now i want to parse it in phonegap(android).How to do that.
When I save that file on my project and use it then it work, but when i use that file directly on server site then its not working.Is there any permission or plugin needed to access json on server side.

[image]

If in url i pass the "http://some folders/places.php" then it not work.

Comment: Please show your code! You need android.permission.INTERNET.

Comment: Theres a typo, you will call plases.json as url not places.php.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. Its working now.I try it on phone and its working.Actually my AVG software block my emulator to access the internet. Thats why it was not working.